# Traefik - apply middleware to router except a specific path

Tags: traefik

I use a IP whitelist middleware to filter the access of my web application to some IPS only and it works.

But, I want to unprotect a specific path to make it public (the path is `/api/transaction`).

For now, I have (in my `docker-comose.yml`) :

```
varnish:
  labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish.rule=Host(`api.local`, `api`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish.middlewares=https-redirect@file"
    - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish.middlewares=https-whitelist@file"
    - "traefik.http.services.api_varnish.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

This part works, then I added:

```
    # Open middleware for payment IPN calls
   - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish_transaction.rule=(Host(`api.local`, `api`) && PathPrefix(`/api/transaction`))"
   - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish_transaction.tls=true"
   - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish_transaction.priority=2"
   - "traefik.http.routers.api_varnish_transaction.middlewares=https-redirect@file"
```

I duplicated the lines, but I didn't apply the middleware `https-whitelist@file` to the new host.

It doesn't work, I can't find the correct syntax or be sure if I can do it ? documentation is pretty poor.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have 2 routers, 1 for /api/transaction and another one for /* and give the first router a higher priority (set a higher number) e.g.

```yaml
# ...
    labels:
        - traefik.http.routers.router_1.priority=2
```

Now requests to /api/transaction will only hit router_1

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#priority

Comment: This is what I did, I updated my question, but the middleware is still applied :(

Comment: I tested it locally and it works for me. Here is a gist of what I am trying out: https://gist.github.com/kamikazechaser/0dd3dae80c78ac2206d1cc22a12a0c18

Comment: Thank you for your time ! regarding to your configuration, it now works ! thanks really

Comment: Could you answer this please ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001082/traefik-ingressroute-url-should-redirect-to-a-default-path